# Adding parameters to an invoked PHP script from Python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

I use the subprocess object in Python to invoke a PHP script. The script runs just fine and I can get the output from the process.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("php /route/to/my/script/php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

However, I require to send some parameters to the script. How can I do this. I would assume I need to send a post via one of the parameters of Popen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use args in the terminal:

- http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.argv.php

Imagine you want to pass String arguments `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`.

Your python class then should look like

> proc = subprocess.Popen("php /route/to/my/script/php arg1 arg2 arg3", shell=True,
>   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

then the vardump of for the parameters would look like

```
<?php var_dump($argv);  ?>
```

and would return:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "script.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "arg1"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "arg2"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "arg3"
}
```

So thats how you could add parameers